How to execute an ssh session defined by a string, in the same shell?
Problem:
I've got a script that generates an ssh command string to generate an ssh session to a remote shell. I want to run this like the following:
function_name args | bash

However it executes the ssh command in a subshell (apologies if that's the wrong terminology) and I can't then use it.
What's the correct way to run this so it executes in the same shell, and I can then write into that shell?
Aside:
For those who wanted the function, it's:
function shortcut_for_ssh(){
   grep ssh notesfile | grep $1
}

Yields
ssh user@hostname


Why does function_name generate a string that has to be executed by bash, rather than just running ssh itself?

can you show your function definition please and an example instantiation of that.
here's a trivial example
function remoteRun()
{
ssh ${1}@${2} "${3}"
}
remoteRun someuser somehost somecommand

Source it.
. <( function_name args )

That or an exec or something like it.
I will assume you trust the function ...

Exactly what I needed!
